# Google Sheet Importrange: Parse error keeps getting back

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I need some help with integrating data from one Google Sheet in another. I keep getting a formula parse error, no idea why. Does anyone see it?

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a5Ht_mZ-h-m9axoQRpceLbpRuT4eUwWC/edit#gid=431384760", "resultaat!A1")
```

Thanks in advance!

I tried a lot of different combinations. Can't see why I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

*Your sheet locale could be using semicolon convention. [Here's an article](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/) explaining the syntax differences based on sheets location setting. try:*

```
=IMPORTRANGE(<SPREADSHEET_ID>; "resultaat!A1")
```